# Threading a bool function passing string argument

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, argument-passing

I am new working with threads.. but I got the concept and have been playing with it in the last days.
But now I am trying to create a thread calling a bool function and passing a string as argument. The code is basically:

```
bool className::analyseData(const std::string& filename) {
  ...
  return true;
}

bool className::equalise(...) {
  ...
  const std::string filename0 = filenameBase + "_chip" + ss.str() + "_0";
  std::thread analyse_dat0(analyseData, &filename0);
  ...
  return true;
}
```

and then I call equalise from other place.

But when I try to compile it I get the following error:

> ```
> SpidrEqualisation_multi_threading.cpp:140:50: error:
> no matching function for call to ‘std::thread::thread(<unresolved overloaded function type>, const string&)
> ```
>
> std::thread analyse_dat0(analyseData, filename0);`

Any idea about how I can fix that?

Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to pass a pointer to that thread function:

```
  std::thread analyse_dat0(analyseData, filename0); // omit the &
                                                    // address of operator
```

Comment: Of course you'll need `std::cref` to not make a copy.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I tried to pass the pointer as a simple try.
It does not work without the pointer as well... The posted error message if for the case without the '&'

Comment: @MateusVicente This alone won't work if `analyseData` is a non-static member function of `className`. You'll need `analyse_dat0(&className::analyseData, this, filename0);` (and you probably should use `analyse_dat0(&className::analyseData, this, std::cref(filename0));`. In the future please post SSCCEs to avoid these iterations where we try to guess what the next problem with your code is.

Comment: @MateusVicente An additional point is you cannot actually use the return value of that function, when the `std::thread` is joined. You'll probably need another (output) [`std::ref()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) parameter passed to the thread function, to return it to the caller.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `std::thread` for this purpose why not use `std::async` and get the result as `std::future` ? That's much simpler, IMO.

```
Class c; 
auto ft = std::async([&] { return c.analyseData("file.txt"); });    
bool result = ft.get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `&` from `td::thread analyse_dat0(analyseData, &filename0);` as you want a reference not a pointer in analyseData.
Also you need to provide an object as analyseData isn't static.